# Done button on keyboard won't work when maximum characters reached in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am limiting the number of allowed characters in my textfield using the following code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  let newLength = (textField.text!).characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
  return newLength <= 10
}
```

This works fine. But when 10 characters have been inputted, pressing 'Done' has no effect and doesn't close the keyboard.

I put the following line before `return newLength <= 10` to debug:

```
print("textField.characters.count = \((textField.text!).characters.count), string.characters.count = \(string.characters.count)., range.length = \(range.length). So newLength = \(newLength)")
```

These are the results (each line appears after a character has been typed):

```
textField.characters.count = 0, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 1
textField.characters.count = 1, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 2
textField.characters.count = 2, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 3
textField.characters.count = 3, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 4
textField.characters.count = 4, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 5
textField.characters.count = 5, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 6
textField.characters.count = 6, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 7
textField.characters.count = 7, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 8
textField.characters.count = 8, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 9
textField.characters.count = 9, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0. So newLength = 10
```

All well and good. But when I then press 'Done', instead of closing the keyboard and calling the function I hooked up to 'Did end on exit', nothing happens on screen and I get this:

`textField.characters.count = 10, string.characters.count = 1., range.length = 0.` So `newLength = 11`.

Repeated presses on 'Done' spits out that last line over and over. Can somebody please help me close the keyboard by pressing Done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really solve this, but came up with a workaround by allowing the user to close the keyboard by tapping anywhere else on the screen. So hopefully when the 'Done' button doesn't work if the maximum characters have been reached, the user will try tapping elsewhere. Far from ideal, but it'll do for now.

In case anyone wants to know, I did this by adding the following to     `viewDidAppear`:

```
// Closes keyboard when tapping anywhere else on screen
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSingleTap:")
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Then I added the following function:

```
func handleSingleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
 self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with the following code:-
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
   if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
            {
                return NO;
            }

            NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
            return newLength <= 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need an answer in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   if (range.length + range.location > count(textField.text) )
    {
        return false;
    }
  let newLength = count(textField.text) + count(string) - range.length
  return newLength <= 10
}
```

Comment: I get the following error message with this code: 
'Cannot invoke 'count' with an argument list of type '(String?)'